# array with positive double-digit random numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

Write a program that fills a 15-byte array with positive double-digit random numbers. in each number, the sum of the two digits is equal to 9.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
int one = 0;
int two = 0;
int[] arr = new int[15];
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = rnd.Next(10, 99);
    one = arr[0] % 10;
    two = arr[0] / 10;

    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0 && one + two == 9)
        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should at least show us what you have tried so far

Comment: *I dont know how to write the program*  and how would you learn anything if someone else does your homework?

Comment: This isn't a service for doing your homework for you. **If this problem is too hard for you, start by solving an easier problem**.  Can you write a program that fills a 15 byte array with the two-digit number 18? That fulfills all the requirements of your program except the "random" part; you have then reduced the problem to figuring out how to generate random numbers that meet a constraint.  If you can't do that, **find a simpler problem you can solve**.  That is what computer programming is all about: turning solutions to simpler problems into solutions to harder problems.

Comment: the math part should be easy, start with 1, so 1+8=9, also 2+7, 3+6, 4+5, 5+4, 6+3 and so on. in order to get 18 from 1 and 8 you do 1*10+8. go ahead and try to implement it. (hint: use a loop)

Comment: I know it is not a service for doing my homework. However, this is a forum for asking a questions. I am sorry if I assualt anyone. This is my program so far: 
            int two = 0;
            int[] arr = new int[15];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = rnd.Next(10, 99);
                one = arr[0] % 10;
                if (arr[i] % 2 == 0 && one + two == 9)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
                }
            }

Comment: thank you! I edited the questions so you can see what I have done by now

Comment: There is nothing on the output. Just "Press any key to cuntinue..."

Comment: no worries, in case you want to mention people that commented on your post use `@username` for example @M.kazemAkhgary so they get a notification.

Comment: thanks you! you helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that `rnd.Next(10, 99)` will not always produce number with the properties that you want. you should write a code that always works.

We know that sum of digits of a number should be 9. if we assume our two-digit number to be `a*10+b` where `a` and `b` are digits and `a + b = 9`, we can randomly generate `a` from 1 to 9.

Then we can calculate other digit `b = 9 - a`.

therefor our final result would be `a*10 + 9 - a` which will be simplified to `a*9 + 9` where `a` is random number from 1 to 9, here are two examples.

```
a=7 then 7 * 9 + 9 = 72, 7 + 2 = 9
a=3 then 3 * 9 + 9 = 36, 3 + 6 = 9
```

note that `a` is in this range `1 <= a < 9`